# Are "topic" "issue" and "subject" interchangeable in a classroom?

Tags: difference, idiomatic-language

Cambridge Dictionary gives this definition about issue

> a subject or problem that people are thinking and talking about

So, I guess "issue" and "subject" are interchangeable when talking about a specific issue/subject.

Imagine an English teacher starts their lesson with

> Today's topic is simple present tense
>
> Today's issue is simple present tense
>
> Today's subject is simple present tense

I guess all of them are grammatical and idiomatic, right?

Comment: Hi, this question needs more work - you're asking for 3 statements to be checked, which is off-topic, and you haven't shown any research you might have made, even though you are suggesting they might be right.

Comment: @Astralbee Thanks for your reminder. The right way would be to ask 3 questions as: (1) "issue" and "subject"; (2) "topic" "issue" (3) "topic" "subject". Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Topic" and "subject" are fairly close, though "subject" is broader. It might apply to a whole semester of material. "Issue" is much narrower, and refers to something that is controversial. Don't use "issue" in that context unless there is some debate about it. The best fit for your context is "topic".